# How do I use CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS in C# with Xamarin?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, syntax, xamarin.android

For my text-to-speech app I'm trying to translate the following Java code:

```
            if (resultCode == TextToSpeech.Engine.CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS) {      
                myTTS = new TextToSpeech(this, this);
            }
```

With Xamarin and C3 the CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS is unavailable, and I can't see which constant to use instead.
I haven't figured out yet what this variable even means.

How do I do something similar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems those integer `const` definitions are missing but the string-based one are defined(?), but a quick check in the Android APIs has it defined as an int with a value of one, so how about:

```
public const int CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS = 0x00000001;
```

> #### public static final int CHECK_VOICE_DATA_PASS
>
> Added in API level 4
>
> Indicates success when checking the installation status of the resources used by the TextToSpeech engine with the ACTION_CHECK_TTS_DATA intent.
>
> Constant Value: 1 (0x00000001)

Comment: So what it should be? 

I tried with if(resultCode == 1)  but it is giving me error. Can you please help.

Comment: @Receme ? What is the error? Post a question with the code and details of the error you are receiving.